# How do I sum the respective elements of two arrays into another array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, merge

I have two arrays:

```
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var arr2 = [2, 3, 4, 5];
```

I want the final array to be:

var arr3 = [3, 5, 7, 9]

If possible, how could I use a callback to carry this out?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `Array.map` (see [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map))

```js
const arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const arr2 = [2, 3, 4, 5];
const sums = arr1.map((v, i) => v + arr2[i]);
document.querySelector('#result').textContent = JSON.stringify(sums);
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Comment: may I ask you why you put the second array after the function, instead of just doing
    function(v, i) {return v + [2,3,4,5][i];}

Comment: It's a possibility, but using that pattern every iteration requires creation of the array. I presume that's not very efficient.

Answer (score 1):

Simply,

```
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var arr2 = [2, 3, 4, 5];
var arr3 = [];
var i = 0;

for (; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    arr3[i] = arr1[i] + arr2[i];
}

console.log(arr3);
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Dipak1991/awmf40j0/1)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through array and sum up values

```js
  var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  var arr2 = [2, 3, 4, 5];
  var arr3 = [];

  for (i in arr1) {
    arr3[i] = arr1[i] + arr2[i];
  }

  console.log(arr3);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this,

```
function myFun(){ 
var arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var arr2 = [2, 3, 4, 5];
var arr3 = [];
var i = 0;
if(arr1.length == arr2.length){
for (; i < arr1.length; i++) 
arr3 [i] = arr1[i] + arr2[i];
console.log(arr3 );
} else{
console.log("Both arrays length are not equal");
}
}
```